# Covariance Matrix is all zeros and Correlation Matrix is all nan for my test matrix

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

So I have the matrix:

```
t = np.array([[2,2],
              [2,2]])
```

When i get its covariance.

```
covx = np.cov(x)
```

I get:

```
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

When I get its covariance matrix I also get a zero matrix:

```
corrx = np.corrcoef(x)
[[ nan   nan]
 [ nan  nan]]
```

I am bit confused if this is the right answer for this matrix or am I missing some math that explains this case since I had the expectation that the correlation matrix always follows this format:

```
correlations [[ 1.  x]
              [ x   1]]
```

Comment: The correlation is computed based on the covariance, which is 0 in this case, so you get 0/0 which is NaN. For more details, visit the docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html#numpy.corrcoef

Comment: And the covariance matrix is zero because it measures variability in data. All elements in `t` are the same so there is no variability -> zero variance (diagonal elements), zero covariance (off-diagonal elements).